# How do you search the Dataset suggestions?

Tags: socrata

See https://nycopendata.socrata.com/nominate

We'd like to be able to download all the suggestions and the responses and all the metadata (dates, etc)

For example, it seems that the answer to most questions one of the New York City open data portal suggestions areas is: "NYC OpenData Thanks for the request. We'll forward this to the appropriate agency."  But the suggestion never seems to be updated again.  Also why don't we measure how NYC DOITT or whatever city agency actually uses the open portal data. It seems that we brag about how much data is there but no one measures how it is used or even if it is used or even complete or accurate.  We find some of the data to be incomplete.  For example, DOB Jobs is not complete since it does not include important updates.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback Ralph! Unfortunately there's no public API or export functionality available for the suggest a dataset functionality.

However, our product team is gathering feedback that'll feed into how that feature will evolve. I'll pass this feedback onto them, and so that hopefully we don't turn into a similar black hole, see if I can get one of them to come comment here too.

Answer (score 0):

This is Christian from Socrata's Product team here. Like Chris said, we definitely appreciate the feedback on the suggestion tool itself to ensure NYC can provide more, and more valuable information via this channel. It is something we're looking at to improve the quality of engagement between government staff and the citizens they serve.

To your comment about measuring impact and usage rather than just volume of data published, you may have seen NYC's analytics dashboard (see: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/analytics), and their more high-level 'open data dashboard' (see: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/stories/s/es39-eesr). Other measures of usage and impact are something we're collaborating with the NYC team on currently.

Thanks for the note!
Christian